# Is there a way to search a struct in a Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Spark Scala, I have Dataframe where one of column is struct type (`state` column below table)

| JobID | State |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{"life_cycle_state": "RUNNING", "state_message": "In run"}` |
| 2 | `{"life_cycle_state":"INTERNAL_ERROR","state_message":"Notebook not found"}` |

Now, I want to filter dataframe with `state` column having ERROR.

Line of code which I've tried :

```scala
val errorJobRunsDF = df.filter(col("state").rlike("ERROR").select("JobID")
```

and it failed because rlike doesn't work for struct type with below error:

> Cannot resolve '`state` RLIKE 'ERROR'' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`state`' is of struct<life_cycle_state:string,state_message:string> type.

Kindly suggest some work arounds.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)